# Uploading Images using ios to php

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

The images I try to upload from my Iphone gallery are all saved as `ipodfile.jpg`

I want the exact image name which I am selecting from the gallery 
and I want to create a folder (with the login username) and I want to store inside the folder

For example

- Username : Mike
- Image    : welcome.jpg

Then I want to create a folder named `mike` and save the image inside.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];

    img = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //images.image = img; 
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.1.92/Abdul/IOS/Chat/upload_file.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
    ;
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Successfully uploaded");

}
```

This is the server-side code I'm using

```
<?php
$oname=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$tempname=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$path="upload";

echo "Upload: " . $oname . "<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $tempname . "<br />";


echo "<br>";
$ex=file_exists("upload/$oname");

if($ex)
{
    echo "File Already exist";
}
else
{
    $upload=move_uploaded_file($tempname,$path.$oname);

    if($upload)
    {
        echo "Sucessfully Stored in: " . $path. $oname;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Not stored Sucessfully : " . $path.$oname;
    }
}
```

Comment: your problem isphp side ya ios side tell me?

Comment: In ios code there is a line filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\" how to change file name what i am selecting from image gallery

Comment: your image is by default save ipodfile.jpg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take unique file name for every image like timestamp which will always be unique.

in below line you are setting image name so set it with time stamp.

```
 [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

You can kepp unique name aomething like this which i have used once,

```
            NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
            NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
            NSString* cleanedString = [[localDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
            NSString *cleanedString2 = [cleanedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",i];
            NSString *finalUniqueImageNAme = [cleanedString2 stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
```

Hope this will help ;)

Update :

you can use unique name like this,

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",finalUniqueImageNAme] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And second thing you should use `AFNetworking` to do this kind of stuff. it'll manage all this kind of stuff like set boundary etc. [Click here for AFNetworking github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Update 2 (according to query of comment):

You should use `NSURLSession` instead of `nsurlconnection` because connection is deprecated now so your code should be like this

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];


[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (data) {

        //if response is in string format
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //if response in json format then
        id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    }



}]resume];
```

Comment: How to implement the uniquename code in the bellow line           [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Ya thanks it working and what this i variable stand for in this line  NSString *cleanedString2 = [cleanedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",i];

Comment: If you feel this is helpful then mark right the answer and up vote it so other person having same problem can use it. I think i have written this code in for loop for multiple image. so everytime title append with 0,1,2,3 like wise. you can comment this line and update last line like `NSString *finalUniqueImageNAme = [cleanedString stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];`

Comment: another one doubt. after uploaded success I required response from php so I have made echo "succesffully uploaded" how to get that response.

Comment: I don't have much idea about php. but i can tell the how to retrieve it from ios. what  are you returning from php ? means string or json object?

Answer (score 0):

changes the path to

`$path="mike/";` and then upload image. By this way your image will be uploaded in mike folder.

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);

    NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.92/Abdul/IOS/Chat/upload_file.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",img] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: I have created a folder mike in php server and tried but it is storing outside the folder not inside the mike folder.

Comment: [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mike\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", 1]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: change php side path name

Comment: No I am getting error : EXE_BAD_ACCESS CODE=2 LIKE THAT

Comment: IN PHP ALSO I CHANGE TO MIKE

Comment: in this line I am getting error                                                                                [[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",img] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];             like expected Identifier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109320/discussion-between-abdulheru-and-darji-jigar).